# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called after first 5 cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

My table is relatively simple and not radically different from many I've done before. Yet `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is only called on the first 5 cells of the table. After that, the debug statement does not appear when I tap. I've researched this issue here and have ruled out some possibilities that are mentioned in other questions:
- the table delegates are properly set.
- a `GestureRecognizer` (that I've set) is not swallowing the presses.
- `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not implemented

Below is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Let me know what else I can provide that can help solve this problem.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    NSLog(@"didSelect");
    NSArray *visibleCells = [partOfSpeechTable visibleCells];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSNumber *checkedState = [checkedStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([checkedState boolValue]) 
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [checkedStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];
    }
    else 
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [checkedStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];
    }

    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
```

(I can comment out all the accessory stuff and it makes no difference).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are the 5 cells the only ones visible without scrolling?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Santa. Actually, after giving up after and posting here, I found the answer right after. My table was sitting in another UIView that I was using to slide certain elements vertically, and that UIView was not long enough to contain the table. So the table would display in full, but the part of the table past the cut off of the containing view did not respond to user interaction. I will post this as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that the containing view was shorter than the table itself. The table displayed in full, but the parts below the cut off of the containing view did not respond to user interaction. The solution was to increase the size of the containing view.

Comment: how to increase containing view size please help i have same problem in tableview .Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I searched forever to find the answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar kind of issue its probably because of

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    
        return 20;
}
```

set the size of  that cell so it can fit in view.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had the same problem with Jason. In my case, only the cell on the first row wasn't calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I increased the containing view of the tableview in xib file (or you could do programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

If `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called only for some cells and the app is running in the simulator then try to reset the simulator.

Menu `Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings...`